# Why do we need to add .clearfix after every 12th column in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am studying bootstrap from [this online tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php#responsive-class). In *Creating Multi-Column Layouts with Bootstrap 3 Grid System* section they say:

> If height of any column is taller than the other it doesn't clear properly and break the layout. To fix this, use the combination of a .clearfix class and the responsive utility classes.

I tried giving different heights to columns within a row. I found that that I do not need `.clearfix`, because the layout is not breaking. Applying `.clearfix` or not appplying it doesn't make any difference to the layout.

**Without `.clearfix:**

```css
@import  url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css")

p {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #dbdfe5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 la box</p>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>  -->

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 6</p>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>  -->

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 9</p>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>  -->

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 11</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**With `.clearfix`:**

```css
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 last boxBox 3 la box</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 6</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 9</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 11</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>Box 12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, why use `.clearfix` if doesn't make any difference?

Comment: I don't know, for some reason `@import url()` isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap's own documentation gives a good example of why in its [Responsive Column Resets section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets):

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a `.clearfix` and our responsive utility classes.
>
> ```html
> <div class="row">
>     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
>     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
>
>    <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
>     <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
>
>    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
>     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
>   </div>
> ```

This is what the example markup they use looks like with the `.clearfix` class in place:

> [image: with .clearfix]

This is what it looks like without it:

> [image: without .clearfix]

Comment: Ah.. I needed to make the first column taller to see the problem -- I made the last one taller. Thanks I got it now.